# Concrete5 - Get a list of file sets a file belongs to

Tags: concrete5, concrete

For a conditional in a block view I am building, I need to be able to check which file sets an image file belongs to.

Scouring documentation, I have found resources as far as listing files if you know the file set name or id, or listing all file sets, but nothing regarding starting with a file, and retrieving all associated file sets.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

More specifically what I am trying to do: the conditional would check to see if the file of an image thumbnail in a carousel belongs to more than one image set, if it doesn't, it opens a larger thumbnail in a lightbox. If it does, it instead populates the lightbox with a hard-coded 360° rotating image gallery block with the alternate file set as source. The missing piece here is retrieving the file sets the starting image belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

In Concrete5 pre 5.7, in the file model, you have the public function getFileSets() that does just that.

Say you have a file object $f you would do:
$sets = $f->getFileSets();

as far as I can tell, the function still exists in 5.7.x